# How to set a local git project to remote?

Tags: git, github

I'm very new to github and want to know how I can push or setup a local project to the remote environment? For example I have a project in C:\project how can I send this to  github  remote? I keep failing  when using git console . Any steps ?

Comment: `I keep failing when using git console` It could help if you explain what you're trying with the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site below will give a hint to what to do. I think it will help .
https://help.github.com/articles/pushing-to-a-remote/

1.First redirect to the git project you want to set.

2. git init
3. git add *
4. git push

Answer (score 3):

Steps I use:

```
create a local repository, if not yet,
commit local repository locally,
      git add .
      git commit -am "init"
create a repository on github with same name as local repo:
      left it empty, no README or .gitignore file,
config remote:
      git remote add origin https://github.com/[user]/[project_name].git

set remote url:
      git config remote.origin.url https://[user]@github.com/[user]/[project_name]

initial push to github:
      git push -u origin master

set tracking info - master:
      git branch --set-upstream-to origin/master
      tip:
            before do this, the remote repo should at least contain 1 commit,
            you can do this by push once, or create a file remotely (e.g. README.md).

check the project on github, to see is it ok.
```

---

In case you have multiple branch locally, and you want track multiple branch with github, not just master.

```
steps - push another branch to github:
* make sure both local/remote have the same branch already,
      if not yet, you can push a local branch to remote first,
      format:
          git push [remote] [branch]
* in local
      switch to specific branch,
      then set its upstream via:
            git branch --set-upstream-to=<remote>/<remote_branch> <local_branch>
      e.g.
            git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/develop develop
*
```

---

place to learn git

- [git-scm.com/documentation](http://git-scm.com/documentation)
- man git xxx

  xxx is the inside command name of git, e.g. add

Answer (score 1):

If your current working folder has not been initialized by Github, then use following commands:

```
git init
git remote add origin <the http git address of your remote repository>
git add .
git commit -m "<some comments for this commit>"
git push origin master
```

If your working copy has been initialized, and you would like to change remote target repository to another one. Then I believe the following commands would help:

```
git remote set-url origin <the address of your new repository>
git add .
git commit -m "<some comments>"
git push origin <the branch you want to push to>
```

Hope this answer is useful!